# Set value to input type="date" from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I want to assign value to my HTML tag `input type="date"` from C# codebehind in ASP.NET web application. After page is loaded, the value is not visible, but in chrome dev tools i can see the value:

[image]

**ASPX:**

```
<input type="date" runat="server" id="date_datumPrispetja" value="dd. MM. yyyy" />
```

**Codebehind:**

```
string date = myDate.ToString("dd. MM. yyyy"); //value of date: "09. 04. 2017";
date_datumPrispetja.Value = date;
```

Is this is even possible, to assign value from codebehind to this HTML5 element?

---

***EDIT:***

Compare on `datetime` and `date` input type.
**C#:**

```
date_datumPrispetja.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd. MM. yyyy");
hi.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd. MM. yyyy");
```

**ASPX:**

```
<input type="date"  runat="server" id="date_datumPrispetja" value="dd. MM. yyyy"/>
<br />
<input type="datetime" runat="server" id="hi" value="dd. MM. yyyy" />
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it should be work, where did you put this code in:

```
string date = myDate.ToString("dd. MM. yyyy"); //value of date: "09. 04. 2017";
date_datumPrispetja.Value = date;
```

Page_Load()?

My test code as bellow:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hi.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
```

Then it worked well.

Comment: Can you show me your `<input>` element definition in your aspx, please?

Comment: Sure. <input type="datetime" runat="server" id="hi" value="dd. MM. yyyy" />

Comment: I need a date picker in same input, so datetime doesnt work for me.

Comment: The type is doesn't matter. I changed the type to Date & still get the current experiences.

Comment: And from the screenshot you provided, the value actually is correct but not showing in the browser, so looks like it's not refresh the latest value in browser?

Comment: Aha, I found the root cause. You should use:DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); rather than DateTime.Now.ToString("dd. MM. yyyy"); in Page_Load. See more details from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212527/how-to-set-default-value-to-the-inputtype-date

Comment: Yes! It works, thanks for all your help, maybe you should edit the main answer, so it will be correct.

Answer (score 3):

This Worked for me.

```
TextBox.Text = Convert.ToDateTime('01-01-2020').Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Safari, Firefox and Chromium accept the date value only in format

```
<input type="date" value="2017-04-27">
```

and will print the date in the localized format. If they get a localized format as input (e.g. "27.04.2017") they print placeholders only.

However Safari accepts

```
<input type="date" value="27.04.2017">
```

On the other hand if Safari get the input format "2017-04-27", it will print this value in a non localized form.

Inside the browser's DOM the input value is stored attribute *defaultValue* (true for all browsers) and the attribute *value* is empty (not true for Safari).

My workaround for this confusion is some javascript:

```js
$(function () {
    var datefields = $('.TTMMJJ')
    for (i = 0; i < datefields.length; i++) {
        datefields[i].type = "date";
        var defaultVal = datefields[i].defaultValue;
        var val = datefields[i].value;
        if (defaultVal.length > 0 && val.length == 0) {
            var darr = defaultVal.split(".");
            if (darr.length == 3) {
                var year = darr[2];
                var month = darr[1];
                var day = darr[0];
                if (year.length == 2) {
                    year = "20" + year;
                }
                var s = year + '-' + month.padStart(2,0) + '-' + day.padStart(2,0);
                datefields[i].value = s;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Note that

```
Date.parse("27.04.2017")
```

works with Chromium but not with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
txtFechaOtorgamiento.Text = Format(servicio.FechaOtorgamiento, "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the format of date string should be "yyyy-MM-dd" as following: `date.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: this answer was not necessary. pls check accepted answer